# How to export an image from MATLAB to a certain cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, matlab

I wanted to export a figure plotted in MATLAB into a specified cell in Excel. I tried [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42079-writing-matlab-image-to-excel-file-at-a-specific-position) but it does not work for the last line and I get the following error:

> No appropriate method, property, or field Pictures for class
>   Interface.Microsoft_Excel_15.0_Object_Library._Worksheet.

The code is:

```
% Open Excel file.
objExcel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
objExcel.Workbooks.Open(fullfile('D:\MATLAB', 'x1.xlsx'));
oWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add();
oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;
oSheet.Range('A1').Select;
oSheet.Pictures.Insert('D:\MATLAB\v.jpg').Select();  % This line does not work for me and I get the error above!
```

Can anyone help me? Is there any other approaches to import the image into Excel from MATLAB? Thanks in advance!